# For any $a>1$ and $b>1$, we have $a^{\log b}=b^{\log a}.$ ("Algorithm Design" by Jon Kleinberg and Eva Tardos) Is this an erratum?

Tags: soft-question, logarithms

I am reading "Algorithm Design" by Jon Kleinberg and Eva Tardos.

> Here we use a very handy identity, which says that, for any $a>1$ and $b>1$, we have $a^{\log b}=b^{\log a}.$

I think if $a>0$ and $b>0$, then $a^{\log b}=b^{\log a}$ holds.

Is this an erratum??

Comment: What makes you think it is wrong?

Comment: It's not false, so I would not call it an erratum. It's just a statement that also is true more broadly than the context that the author uses.

Comment: Of course, for any $a>1$ and $b>1$, we have $a^{\log b}=b^{\log a}$.

Comment: I think we don't usually write for example $1/(1-x)=1+x+x^2+\dots$ holds for $0<x<1/2$ even if we use this formula only for $x=1/4$.

Comment: It is not an error per se.

Comment: geetha290krm, 2'59'2, copper.hat, Thank you very much for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$a^{\log b}=b^{\log a}$$
Is true, because taking $\log$ both sides we get
$$\log b \log a=\log a \log b$$
The only requirement is that $\log a$ and $\log b$ should exist. For this, we require $a,b>0$

Hence, your thinking ($a,b>0$) is necessary that makes the identity more general, $a,b>1$ is automatically covered.

Comment: Z Ahmed, Thank you very much for your answer.